# Get groups of elements from name inside of list C#

Tags: c#

I have a List of :

```
public class GT
{
    public string ActivityName { get; set; }
    public int Seconds { get; set; }

}
```

And the `ActivityName` could repeat through the iteration and what I want to do is, regroup all the items that have the same name and calculate the average of seconds of these specifics items. I tried to use `Distinct` but it didn't group them.

Comment: Please add what you tried and some more code samples for better understanding

Comment: Try following :             List<GT> activities = new List<GT>();
            List<GT> results = activities.GroupBy(x => x.ActivityName).Select(x => new GT() { ActivityName = x.Key, Seconds = (int)x.Average(y => y.Seconds) }).ToList();

Answer (score 3):

You should use `GroupBy` instead of `Distinct`:

```
List<GT> list = /*...*/;
var query = list.GroupBy(x => x.ActivityName, (k,g) => new { ActivityName = k, AverageTimeInSeconds = g.Average(x => x.Seconds) });
```

Comment: @TimSchmelter I would say it depends on what OP needs.

Answer (score 1):

```
var groups = items.GroupBy(p => p.ActivityName)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        ActivityName = g.Key,
        Average = g.Average(t => t.Seconds)
    }).ToList();
```